# Can you use a PS3 controller as a gamepad/joystick in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, game-controller

I'd like to know if it's possible to connect a PS3 controller to a Windows 7 personal computer so it could be used like any other gamepad.

Comment: What happened when you plugged it in and tired it?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @techie007 I'm getting stuck at the high controller price and no official instructions on how to connect it to a PC. I tried asking my retailer who sells them if I can return it if it doesn't work and in four places I got negative answers. So there you go − I'm trying to avoid getting stuck with a controller that can't control anything by asking beforehand if there's a way to make this work.

Comment: @techie007 just FYI, the PS3 controller doesn't connect like a normal gamepad device (no official drivers whatsoever, not that I expected any for a game console controller)... That being said, for the OP, I have been able to use the MotionInJoy software with great success as in Devid's answer below (it forces the controller to be emulated as a virtual gamepad, with a customizable layout from the MotionInJoy software itself).  **Just note that I was connecting the controller via USB**; if you want to use Bluetooth, it's still possible, but is more tricky to setup (MotionInJoy has instructions).

Comment: How necessary is the PS3 controller? A 360 controller should work out of the box with Windows.

Comment: @Laurbert515 I prefer the PS controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. First you will need to download the driver from [here](http://www.motioninjoy.com/download)
   (MotioninJoy). Unzip the file and run the installation software.
2. Now when you plug in your PS3 controller you will see a icon in the
   system tray showing that Windows is installing drivers for your
   controller. At this point the controller will be recognized, but you
   won't be able to use it correctly (it needs to have a button profile loaded *in* MotionInJoy).
3. Now open the DS3 tool, and press the “Load Driver” button. Windows
   will warn you that the publisher is unknown, just ignore the message
   and move on installing the driver. Now your PS3 will be ready for
   use after you see a message SUCCESS: Install Completed. And that's
   it actually. For more information check [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/45610/how-to-use-your-ps-3-controllers-as-a-joystick-for-your-windows-pc/) (How-To-Geek)

Comment: Link-only answers are a no-no due to possible future link-rot.  Please include pertinent information in your answers.

Comment: Ok I will edit tomorrow my answer

Comment: DS4tool works pretty well for my DualShock4 both with usb cable and bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to get the PlayStation controller form factor, but aren't wedded specifically to a PS3 controller (which seems plausible since you mention not having bought one yet), consider instead purchasing an original PlayStation controller, along with a PSX-to-USB adapter such as [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000F6BGXY) -- odds are it'll be cheaper to buy both of those than a single PS3 controller (the linked Amazon page lists both the adapter and a PS2 Dual Shock controller for $26), and you'll get the same form factor without needing to worry about fighting with drivers, since the adapter presents the controller to the PC as a bog-standard USB HID device for which the drivers will be already present.

Comment: I've had a ps1 since its launch and I have the most terrible first-hand experience with those wired controllers. The cable wears and tears around the place where it's attached to the controller, so I'd rather have a wireless one. Or be able to replace a worn out usb cable, since it's probably going to be much easier than soldering that nasty 9-wire cable.

Comment: @user1306322 Really? I've never had any trouble, but it may just be that I don't use the controller heavily enough to wear out the strain relief.